# Xylan vs. Teflon for non-stick food pans?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am looking at non-stick pans and some are Xylan® others, and most, are Teflon™.

- What are the chemical differences?
- What is better for cooking?
- What is better for health safety?

I do know that Teflon can be consumed without a problem, as it is never degraded, but at very high temperatures the fumes are dangerous.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site.

Comment: Xylan and Teflon are basically the same thing but are trademarks belonging to different companies for their specific products.

Answer (score 2):

Both Xylan and Teflon are chemically polytetrafluoroethylene. But a polymer just by name can mean a lot of different things if you consider the structure/arrangement, additives and impurities. These are highly process-dependent and, guess what, we do not know their chemistry for sure because they are industrially protected. For actual matters, both Xylan and Teflon are unsafe above 260 ⁰C (500 ⁰F), when they start to break down to toxic fluorine polymer fumes.